# Is there a way to remap my Magic keyboard's FN and left control button in windows 10?

Tags: windows-10, keyboard, button-remapping, apple

I think WinAppleKey is able to do it, but apparently, I need to open my Windows to be testing mode forever. I'm not too sure how vulnerable that leaves my system

Driver attacks would be really bad. Is there any other way? I tried Windows PowerToys, but <kbd>fn</kbd> key press doesn't register.

It's really annoying. I like the keyboard, but my muscle memory keeps on clicking the bottom left button as <kbd>ctrl</kbd>.

Comment: Check if your UEFI/BIOS has an option for this, something like "Swap CtrI-Fn". Do you run Windows on Apple hardware (and how)?